# Delete all cookies stored in the browser from a local page

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am developing a web application which is launched in a browser by loading the index.html file. (file:///C:Users/xxx/path/index.html)

When my page is loaded, i see in Chrome settings that some cookies have been stored from my previous connexion :

[image]

I would like to delete all cookies of "acustomdomain.com".

I use this code when my local page is loaded but it doesn't work :

```
function deleteAllCookies() {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

For me it's normal, because when i execute document.cookie command in the Chrome console, the result is empty because there is no cookies stored for my local page.

How can i delete the cookie stored for another domain ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the jquery.cookie plugin, you can erase all cookies this way:

```
for (var it in $.cookie()) $.removeCookie(it);
```

Comment: $.cookie() return {} whereas when i go in Chrome Settings i see some cookies for the domain "acustomdomain.com"